# What does typedef cell (*proc_type)(const std::vector<cell> &); do?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was looking at [this post](http://howtowriteaprogram.blogspot.com/2010/11/lisp-interpreter-in-90-lines-of-c.html) when I see this line.

The code, in short, looks like:

```
struct cell {
  typedef cell (*proc_type)(const std::vector<cell> &);
  typedef std::vector<cell>::const_iterator iter;
  typedef std::map<std::string, cell> map;
  cell_type type;
  std::string val;
  std::vector<cell> list;
  proc_type proc;
  environment * env;
  cell(cell_type type = Symbol) : type(type), env(0) {}
  cell(cell_type type, const std::string & val) : type(type), val(val), env(0) {}
  cell(proc_type proc) : type(Proc), proc(proc), env(0) {}
};
```

So what does typedef cell (*proc_type)(const std::vector &);  do?
The typedef is supposed to be used like

```
typedef (existing) (new)
```

So why declaring such a complicated new type when we could just use cell instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assertion that "the typedef is supposed to be used like `typedef (existing) (new)`" is completely incorrect. No, in general case it will not be used like that. Only the most basic typedef declarations might follow that format.

Syntax of typedef declaration in C (or C++) is based on the syntax of ordinary declaration. In fact, it is exactly the same syntax with `typedef` keyword added to it. In these languages the declaration cannot be split clearly into two parts, as you attempted to do in your case. Declaration syntax is much more complicated. The declared name is generally sitting in the middle of the tokens that describe the type of that name.

For a simple example, a declaration for an object named `a` of array type `int [10]` will look as follows

```
int a[10];
```

It has parts to the left of the name (`int`) and to right of the name (`[10]`). Similarly, in a typedef declaration the tokens that describe the type can (and will) reside to the left and to the right of the new type name. In your example

```
typedef cell (*proc_type)(const std::vector<cell> &);
```

the new name `proc_type` is being declared, while everything that surrounds it on both sides actually describes the type `cell (*)(const std::vector<cell> &)` this new typedef name will stand for. It is a pointer type: a pointer to function that receives `const std::vector<cell> &` parameter and returns `cell` value.

Comment: I feel like it is interesting that you are making the connection between an ordinary declaration and the typedef. It is a way of thinking I have never seen. However, I found it rather difficult to understand why my assertion is wrong considering this piece of documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/ when it says "C++ allows the definition of our own types based on other existing data types. We can do this using the keyword typedef, whose format is: typedef existing_type new_type_name ;" Is it wrong or simply another way of understanding?

Comment: @tjinio: Well, in the most simple cases (examples of which you can find in that tutorial) a typedef declaration will indeed follow that format. In exactly the same fashion a simplest variable declaration follows the `<type> <name>;` format. However, this is not true in general case. More precisely, any declarations that directly involve array types and function types will not follow that format. Once you start working with array and function types, you will observe that the type "descriptor" *wraps around* the name being declared from both sides (on the left and on the right)

Comment: The declaration in your original question deals with function type, which is why it does not adhere to that simplified `typedef existing_type new_type_name;` format. So, from the formal point of view that tutorial is wrong. It is interesting to node that one of their examples is `typedef char field [50];` declaration, which is already different from that simple format.

Answer (score 1):

> So what does typedef cell (*proc_type)(const std::vector &); do?

It declares a new type named `proc_type` that is a pointer to a function that uses the compiler's default calling convention (usually `__cdecl`), takes a `const std::vector<cell> &` as input, and returns a `cell`.

Code outside what you have shown will then assign a function to the `cell::proc` member, presumably so that `cell` users can later call that function when needed, without knowing or caring what function is actually being called (in the code you link to, those functions are being assigned in `add_globals()` via the `cell(proc_type)` constructor).

A classic callback scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can deduce complex typedefs like function pointers by pasting them into the online cdecl website:

> http://cdecl.org

Or by using the 'right-left' rule:

> http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html

Answer (score 0):

`typedef cell (*proc_type)(const std::vector &);`

defines `proc_type` as a function pointer type `cell (*)(const std::vector&)`